# Sum of quotients of gamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, gamma-function

I was wondering if there is some closed formula for
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\Gamma(Ln)}{\Gamma(Ln+r)},$$
where $L,N$ are positive integers greater than 1 and $r$ is a non-integer with $1<r<2$.

My approach was to rewrite the expression as
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\Gamma(Ln)}{\Gamma(Ln+r)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathrm{B}(Ln,r)$$
and then use the definition
$$\mathrm{B}(Ln,r)=\int_0^1 t^{Ln-1}(1-t)^{r-1} dt$$
to put the sum inside the integral. The problem I find is that I don't recognize the resulting integral, which is
$$\int_0^1 (1-t)^{r-1}\frac{t^L-t^{L(N+1)}}{t(1-t^L)}dt.$$

Something tells me that a hypergeometric function could appear, but I don't know how to get there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is related to the Fox–Wright function (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function). In particular, your sum is $$
{}_2\Psi _1 \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {(L,L)} & {(1,1)}  \\
   {(r + L,L)} &  -   \\
\end{array};1} \right] - {}_2\Psi _1 \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {(L(N + 1),L)} & {(1,1)}  \\
   {(r + L(N + 1),L)} &  -   \\
\end{array};1} \right].
$$ This is of course not really a closed form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!